# Avoiding shell=True in Popen

Tags: python, windows, shell, popen

I am trying to open a `.txt` file in Windows. The code is as follows:

```
subprocess.Popen("C:\folder\file.txt", shell=True)
```

This works perfectly fine. The default editor is automatically opened and the file is loaded, however, I have read somewhere before that invoking calls through the shell (cmd.exe in Windows) is less safe. How can I do the same without it. Simply setting `shell=False` is giving me the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Now, I can try this as a workaround:

```
subprocess.Popen("notepad C:\folder\file.txt")
```

but this only works if notepad is available, hence loses its generality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using windows then there is the (non portable) [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile) command which will take a file path and open it in the default application for that filetype.

In your case you would do:

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\folder\file.txt")
```

Note that this method *won't* work on Linux and Mac OSX, you'll have to have to use their own utilities for this. (`open` for OSX and `xdg-open` on Linux) and start them with subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you try to use is a builtin thing of the windows cmd.exe. Therefore you need to set the shell=True parameter. The cmd.exe knows what to do with the file you hand in.

If you use shell=False, you try to start the file like a programm and hence nothing happens, since .txt files have no exe-header.

Read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Reading [further](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), you can find why using the shell=True parameter can be a security flaw. If you consider to assemble the parameters by user inputs, you should not use this, otherwise nothing speaks against it.

Anyway, I recommend using your second example, because it is explicit. You decide what program to start.

```
subprocess.Popen("notepad C:\folder\file.txt")
```